# EVP encryption core dumped

Tags: c, encryption, openssl

I'm trying to decrypt a cipher text that was encrypted using `AES_128_cbc()` from `EVP`, the cipher text exist in a file named `task3.bin`. I'm trying to do a mock decryption trial, meaning the decryption is not using the right `key` or `iv`, but are of valid length.

These two functions are copy and pasted from EVP's [documentation page](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/EVP_Symmetric_Encryption_and_Decryption), with the exception that `EVP_aes_256_cbc()` have been changed to `EVP_aes_128_cbc()` as the decryption method.

```
void handleErrors(void) {
  ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
  abort();
}

int decrypt(unsigned char *ciphertext, int ciphertext_len, unsigned char *key,unsigned char *iv, unsigned char *plaintext) {
  EVP_CIPHER_CTX *ctx;

  int len;

  int plaintext_len;

  /* Create and initialise the context */
  if(!(ctx = EVP_CIPHER_CTX_new())) handleErrors();

  /* Initialise the decryption operation. (changed 256 to 128 HERE!!!)*/
  if(1 != EVP_DecryptInit_ex(ctx, EVP_aes_128_cbc(), NULL, key, iv))
    handleErrors();

  /* Provide the message to be decrypted, and obtain the plaintext output.
   * EVP_DecryptUpdate can be called multiple times if necessary
   */
  if(1 != EVP_DecryptUpdate(ctx, plaintext, &len, ciphertext, ciphertext_len))
    handleErrors();
  plaintext_len = len;

  /* Finalise the decryption. Further plaintext bytes may be written at
   * this stage.
   */
  if(1 != EVP_DecryptFinal_ex(ctx, plaintext + len, &len)) handleErrors();
  plaintext_len += len;

  /* Clean up */
  EVP_CIPHER_CTX_free(ctx);

  return plaintext_len;
}
```

Here's my `main` function that's calling `decrypt`

```
int main(void) {
  FILE *f;
  long lSize;
  char *buffer;

  char *ciphertext;
  unsigned char *iv;
  unsigned char *key;

  unsigned char decryptedtext[128];
  int decryptedtext_len;

  // read ciphertext
  f = fopen("task3.bin", "rb");
  fseek( f , 0L , SEEK_END);
  lSize = ftell( f );
  rewind( f );
  ciphertext = calloc( 1, lSize+1 );
  fread(ciphertext , lSize, 1 , f);
  fclose(f);

  // testing key and iv
  key = (unsigned char *)"0123456789012345";
  iv = (unsigned char *)"0000000000000000";

  // decrypt!
  decryptedtext_len = decrypt(ciphertext, strlen((char *)ciphertext), key, iv, decryptedtext);

  return 0;
}
```

I'm getting the error `139864800151232:error:06065064:lib(6):func(101):reason(100):evp_enc.c:529:
Aborted (core dumped)` and I've spent hours looking at it without much success. Anyone skilled at `OpenSSL`, please help.

---

The error comes from `EVP_DecryptFinal_ex`, the last `EVP` call in `decrypt`. I can only assume certain length are not allocated correctly.

Comment: no error checking anywhere - have you at least used a debugger (or printf) to see how far it gets before crashing?

Comment: Yes I have. I've updated my question @john3136

Comment: The padding is checked on the `EVP_DecryptFinal` call, see updated answer.

Comment: Also ciphertext for AES or other modern algorithms is essentially random byte values which can include 0 aka NUL, so **using `strlen` will often give the wrong length** even when there is a 0 afterward as you assured by `calloc`-ing (and thus zeroing) an extra byte. Use the length read, in your example `lSize`.

Answer (score 1):

If you decrypt data that was encrypted with PKCS#7 padding (the usual case) decrypting with an incorrect key will result in a padding error the majority of the time.

Since the padding is in the last block it is checked on the `EVP_DecryptFinal` call so that all makes sense.

Mocking decryption is difficult to impossible depending on the encryption algorithm, mode and padding amount other things.

Note: The OpenSSL EVP docs state: "*OpenSSL uses PKCS padding by default*" which is a cop-out since it doers not state PKCS#5 or PKCS#7. I have to assume PKCS#7 for AES.

Comment: The NOTES section of the man page for `EVP_Encrypt/Decrypt/Cipher*` and `EVP_CIPHER_CTX_*` says "PKCS padding works by adding n padding bytes of value n to make the total length of the encrypted data a multiple of the block size. Padding is always added [even] if the data is already a multiple of the block size ..." That is unambigously PKCS7 even though it doesn't use that label (as I agree it should).